# Rails model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I validate a model in the following scenario. We have three models, being account, time log and project. An account has_many projects, and a project belongs_to account.

When a user creates a time log, they are able to select from a list of projects associated with that account, put in some more details, and save the log.

One of our developers has pointed out that it's possible to manipulate the code going back to the controller when a time log is being saved and if you pass the id of a project belonging to another account back to the controller, that project name then becomes visible in a view. In this way you could build a list of other account's projects, which is not cool.

So what I want to achieve is to validate the record being saved to ensure that the project id is actually a project associated with the current_account.

How would I achieve this?

At the moment, this is how I am building the time log

```
def create
    @log = @employee.time_logs.build(params[:employee_time_log])
    @log.account_id = current_account.id

    if @log.save
      flash[:notice] = "Time log sucessfully saved."
      redirect_to employee_time_logs_path(@employee)
    else
      render :form
    end
end
```

and the time log model looks like this

```
class EmployeeTimeLog < ActiveRecord::Base

  #validations
  validates :date, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true

  #associations
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :company_project
end
```

Comment: I think this is a job for a controller because the model doesn't know what the current_account is. However if current_account is somehow available in the model, you can create [a custom validator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates_with).

Comment: The current_account is not currently available in the model and although thats where I like to do validations I'm not a big fan of passing current_ information back to the model as I've been bitten by it in the past. How would you approach doing it in the neatest way in the controlleR?

Comment: See my answer for a solution in the controller...

Comment: code added for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. This was the solution in the end

```
user_supplied_project_id = params[:employee_time_log][:company_project_id]
timelog_params = user_supplied_project_id == '' ? params[:employee_time_log].merge(company_project_id: '') : params[:employee_time_log].merge(company_project_id: current_account.company_projects.find(user_supplied_project_id).id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about a case of privilege escalation here.

The [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#privilege-escalation) has some tips about this:

> This is alright for some web applications, but certainly not if the user is not authorized to view all projects. If the user changes the id to 42, and they are not allowed to see that information, they will have access to it anyway. Instead, query the user's access rights, too:
>
> @project = @current_user.projects.find(params[:id])

In your case, you want to allow this:

```
@log = @employee.time_logs.build(project_id: 'good', …)
```

and disallow this:

```
@log = @employee.time_logs.build(project_id: 'bad', …)
```

All projects belonging to an account are queried like so:

```
current_account.projects
```

which can be used for further queries:

```
current_account.projects.find('good')
#=> returns a record because ID belongs to account

current_account.projects.find('bad')
#=> raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

And so that's your way of ensuring you have the right project_id passed to your controller!

```
user_supplied_project_id = params[:project_id]
timelog_params = params.merge(project_id: current_account.projects.find(user_supplied_project_id))
@log = @employee.time_logs.build(timelog_params)
```

Comment: Could you explain that a little more, sorry!

Comment: getting a unknown attribute: utf8 on save.

Comment: OK this is now working, but the validation fails if an entry is not made. How can I conditionally do the validation?